# TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE to Time stamp

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle10g, hibernate-mapping

I have a query in my Java class that fetches (Order_num) VARCHAR and Time_Field(TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE) as shown below:

```
select order_num,time_Field from 
MY_TABLE where ORD_NUM='123456789' ORDER BY time_Field desc
```

However it gives me "

> No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101" exception

that I highly doubt is due to the mapping between Oracle database and Hibernate. Because without the "Time_Field" being returned the query runs fine.

Is there a way I can cast or convert the "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" to simple "TIMESTAMP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out by running the below query:

```
SELECT order_num,TO_CHAR(
     FROM_TZ( CAST( time_Field AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' ) 
     AT LOCAL,
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'
   ) AS local_time
FROM   MY_TABLE
where ord_num='123456789'
ORDER BY time_Field desc;
```